# Reflection on IQueryable<T> can't find property

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, dll, webforms

I created a custom gridview control and exported it into a dll so I can reuse it. Inside the dll I created a function to get the DataSource, I'm trying to fill a dropdown from there but is failing.

So on my website I have this

```
public partial class _Management : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class _ManagementHelper
    {
        public int ID;
        public string CompanyName;
        public string ResourceName;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        ucGridViewEx.DataSource = ucGridViewEx_Source();
        ucGridViewEx.DataBind();
    }

    private List<dynamic> ucGridViewEx_Source()
    {
        var source = dl.ComapniesResources.Select(x => new _ManagementHelper
        {
            ID = x.ResourceID,
            CompanyName = x.Supplier1.SupplierName,
            ResourceName = x.Name
        });

        return ucGridViewEx.GridViewExDataSource(source);
}
```

Then the custom control inside the dll have this relevant code

```
public List<dynamic> GridViewExDataSource<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    foreach (var column in this.Columns)
    {
        var gridViewExColumn = column as ColumnEx;
        if (gridViewExColumn != null
            && gridViewExColumn.SearchType == SearchTypeEnum.DropDownList)
        {
            gridViewExColumn.DropDownDataSource = query.GetDropDownDataSource(gridViewExColumn.DataField);
        }
    }

    return ((IQueryable<dynamic>)query).ToList<dynamic>();
}
```

Function GetDropDownDataSource() is inside another extension class inside the same dll as the gridview

```
internal static List<ListItem> GetDropDownDataSource<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
    string dataField)
{
    var ddlSource = new List<ListItem>();

    // x =>
    var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

    // x.Property
    var propery = typeof(T).GetProperty(dataField);

    // x => x.Property
    var columnLambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(xParameter, propery), xParameter);

    return ddlSource;
}
```

Code fails in this where I'm assingning the value to columnLambda because property is null, not because it does not exist (it does) because is not getting any property. I tried with GetProperties() and is not returning anything.

Is curious than this is happening since I moved to the DataSource to select into _ManagementHelper. I was using a dynamic ( Select(x => new {}) ) on ucGridViewEx_Source() before and it worked perfectly. Please don't provide the solution to keep using the dynamic because I need to allow both types, with dynamic and using custom objects.

Answer (score 2):

`_ManagementHelper` has no property. It just contains three fields (as far as you told us). So `GetPrperty` returns nothing. Change the members of `_ManagementHelper` to properties:

```
public class _ManagementHelper
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @md-Unicorn this worked for this case. But I have another request to do, what about if I have a complex query and do ToList<dynamic>().AsQuerable() it does not work neither, same issue no properties found. You have any suggestion on this case? If it's confusing I can modify the first question adding this question

Comment: @vcliment89 I can't guess anything until I see the code. You can edit your question and add your other scenario, or you can ask another question (preferred).

Answer (score 0):

I see one bug --

```
    var source = dl.ComapniesResources.Select(x => new _ManagementHelper
    {
        // ResourceID = x.ResourceID, this was the old code
        ID = x.ResourceID,  // fixed code
        CompanyName = x.Supplier1.SupplierName,
        ResourceName = x.Name
    });
```

also, where is ListItem defined?

Comment: Sorry @Hogan, I did modify the code removing unnecessary code for this question and forgot changing it. I'll correct it